Linux - force certain wlan device to connect to certain network (or none) automatically
Is it possible to force wlan0 on my Raspberry Pi 4 running Debian to connect automatically to a predefined AP while wlan1 does nothing? Or if I need to specify that wlan0 goes always to wifi_1 and wlan1 goes to wifi_2.
I have a problem I need an inbuilt wifi adapter to connect to my phone hotspot and then connect to its IP over SSH or VNC. I need then to use a USB adapter (wlan1) for some monitoring, manual connecting to other networks, etc. The problem is that wlan1 is the one that connects to the hotspot; thus, I cannot use it for the testing because if it disconnects, I cannot control the headless Pi.
Thanks a lot

One of the following posts might help : post1, post2, post3.

@harrymc Thank you for your attribution. But I would prefer a more direct answer. "How to force the device to do what I want". Thanx

You could try those links that relate to your context or not, as you wish.
